# PHP. Как использовать foreach внутри массива?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Хочу реализовать такой код

```
$result = [
'id' => '1',
'result' => [
    'test1' => true,
    'test2' => {
        'test' => [
            foreach(WC() - > cart - > get_cart() as $cart_item) {
                $product = $cart_item['data'];
                if (!empty($product)) {
                    echo {
                        'id' => $product - > id
                    },

                }
            }
        ]
    }


]
```

]

result должен быть таким

```
[
'id' => '1',
'result' => [
    'test1' => true,
    'test2' => {
        'test' => [
           {
                'id' => 1,
            },
            {
                'id' => 2,
            },
            {
                'id' => 3,
            },
            {
                'id' => 4,
            },

        ]
    }


]
```

]

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Скорее никак, да и не нужно. Вынесите цикл до массива, собирайте результат в переменную и выводите его в конечном массиве

Comment: И `{` и `[`. Ты там часом с джсоном не путаешь ничего? В массиве никогда не используются `{}`.

Comment: [Ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$test = [];

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];

    if ( ! empty( $product ) ) {
        $test[] = [ 'id' => $product->id ];
    }
}

$result = [
    'id'     => '1',
    'result' => [
        'test1' => true,
        'test2' => [ 'test' => $test ],
    ],
];
```